# Beginner plumbing kitchen sink, high waste pipe, can I use reversible p trap?

Tags: plumbing, kitchens, kitchen-sink

I am replaced existing drop in 2 bowl sink with a single bowl undermount sink. I knew the waste pipe was high but I am running into issues fitting the dishwasher wye tail pipe.
Would a reversible p trap be a possible option (located in IL)

The pic below is the temporary set up we have now, the dishwasher drain is in the wrong place, trying to fix it.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The packing material says "UPC" on it, i.e. Uniform Plumbing Code. It's explicitly designed as "Reversible J-B...." That's good enough for me.

The UPC references ASME A112.18.2, where this (110 USD) document prescribes design of traps. If a building official held my feet to the fire, then I would look for an explicit "conforms to ASME A112.18.2" on the packaging instead of that vague "UPC."